# if statement not recognizing value even though console.log confirms it

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, textfield, getelementbyid

I am trying to make a contact list in HTML. When adding a new contact, a menu comes up in which the user can enter information about the contact. For some reason, when I try to console.log the values of any of the fields (as I need to use the firstnamefield field to determine whether or not the contact is valid), it says that it can not find the value of null. As a result, my if statements aren't working and I am unable to keep the user from making a totally blank contact.

Code below, any help appreciated.

```
function addContact() { //called by the "add contact button", inserts the fields for the custom
      document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="<h2><input type='text' id='firstnamefield' placeholder='First Name' value=''></h2><h2><input type='text' id='middlenamefield' placeholder='Middle Name'></h2><h2><input type='text' id='lastnamefield' placeholder='Last Name'></h2><input type='text' id='nicknamefield' placeholder='Nickname'><br><br><input type='text' id='phonefield' placeholder='Phone'><br><input type='text' id='emailfield' placeholder='Email'><br><br><input type='text' id='birthdayfield' placeholder='Birthday'><br><button type='button' id='finishbutton' onclick='finalizeContact()'>Finished</button>";
}

function finalizeContact() { //called by the "finished" button on the contact information form that appears when adding a contact, turns the information that has just been input by the user into a contact under the custom section at the bottom of the list
  var firstname=document.getElementById('firstnamefield').value;
  console.log(firstname);
  if(document.getElementById("firstnamefield").value != null || firstname != '') {
    document.getElementById('custom').innerHTML = document.getElementById('custom').innerHTML + "<button type='button' class='customcontact' onclick=\"display('" + document.getElementById('firstnamefield').value + "', '" + document.getElementById('nicknamefield').value + "', '" + document.getElementById('lastnamefield').value + "', '" + document.getElementById('nicknamefield').value + "', '" + document.getElementById('phonefield').value + "', '" + document.getElementById('emailfield').value + "', '" + document.getElementById('birthdayfield').value + "')\">" + document.getElementById('firstnamefield').value + " " + document.getElementById('lastnamefield').value + "</button>";
    display(document.getElementById('firstnamefield').value, document.getElementById('middlenamefield').value, document.getElementById('lastnamefield').value, document.getElementById('nicknamefield').value, document.getElementById('phonefield').value, document.getElementById('emailfield').value, document.getElementById('birthdayfield').value)
    if(document.getElementById('custom').style.display=="none") { // if there hasn't been a custom contact created yet, the CUSTOM section isn't visible. therefore, if the CUSTOM section is hidden, this function will make it visible
      document.getElementById('custom').style.display="block";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("firstnamefield").style.border = "5px solid red";
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "Please enter a name.<br>" + document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: post your html too

Comment: You use an "OR" when you meant to use an 'AND'

Comment: Instead of a console.log but a debugger and open your chrome Dev tools it will help you much more to debug than one console log. You can inspect all your values and put js in the console that chrome will evaluate

Comment: Your input fields are only being added as innerHTML and not as actual elements in the DOM. Because they are not nodes within the DOM, the finalizeContact function can't find the element and returns null. I recommend using document.createElement to add your input element as nodes to the DOM